# Cant open Jar file which is open using a batch which is opened using another batch file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar, cmd

I am trying to open a batch file which is opened by another batch file which is supposed to launch my jar file.

This is the line of the batch file which I use to open my ServerStart.bat to launch my jar file. (test.bat which is located on my desktop.)

`set runmc1="C:\Game Host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4\ServerStart.bat"`

This is the ServerStart.bat

`java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar nogui`

Then I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnbF5.jpg

I have spent hours all over Google so I'm here to ask you all. Can some please explain why this doesn't work and a way to fix this issue I'm having.

Test.bat:

```
:: Sets the text and background color of the CMD window
color 0a

::=================================================================::
:: Minecraft Server #1                                             ::
::                                                                 ::
:: Window and Log name, replace after =                            ::
set mc1=FTB 1.6.4                                                  
::                                                                 ::
:: Your start command, Replace after =                             ::
set runmc1="C:\Game Host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4\ServerStart.bat"     
::=================================================================::

::=======================::
::   End of variables    ::
::=======================::

:: This will keep the window clean and easy to read
@echo off 

:: Sets the title of the window
title Utility Launcher 1.0

:: This variable takes you back to the main screen
:begining

:: Clears the window incase there is anything there
cls

:: Prints to the window what we are doing

echo Server Utility Launcher 1.0 has been started!
echo.
echo *************************************************
echo To close this Utility Launcher, close this window
echo *************************************************

echo 1. Start FTB 1.6.4
echo.

set /p a=


IF %a%==1 echo Starting %mc1%
cd "C:\Game host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4\"
start %runmc1%
pause
goto begining
```

ServerStart.bat:

```
cd "C:\Game host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4"
java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar "FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar"   nogui
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the jar file RELATIVE to the folder you are executing it.

Try this in your ServerStart.bat

```
java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar "C:\Game Host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4\FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar" nogui
```

so if you execute your ServerStart it will look for the jar in C:\users\username\desktop\FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar where it wont find dit.

To make sure the Minecraft FTB server doesnt create the level files on your desktop you must add the following line before the java command.

```
cd "C:\Game host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4"
```

So in total your bat would be if you want it confined to your directory :

```
 cd "C:\Game host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4"
 java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar "FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar" nogui
```

**EDIT**

try replacing your last lines with this:

```
IF %a%==1 echo Starting %mc1%
cd "C:\Game host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4\"
cmd /C %runmc1%
pause
goto begining
```

Comment: I have tried that then it just recreates the contents of the folder on my desktop!

Comment: Nevermind I got it to launch but its launching in my main cmd window and not opening another one. How do I get to open into a separate window

Comment: if you do `cd "C:\Game host\mc_ftb_monster-1.6.4" [press enter here]
 java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=128m -jar "FTBServer-1.6.4-965.jar" nogui` in cmd(without a batch file) do you get the desired result? if so, there is something wrong in your batch file.

Comment: well you changed into the right directory, and if you execute the java command there?

Comment: Im trying to get this too launch in a separate window and in getting this result: http://i.imgur.com/DwVZUFW.jpg I need this result: http://i.imgur.com/hYDMzIH.jpg. What im trying to accomplish is it auto start it instead of me having to enter ServerStart.bat ever time

Comment: please update your question with the complete contents of both bat files as you have them now.

Comment: ... Update... **your question** with the **complete** contents of both bat files

Comment: see my edit. I changed the way you start your minecraft launcher.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I'm sorry im new to this. Everything works perfectly now.

Comment: I love criticism, without I can't learn/ learn from my mistakes. Thumbs up to you friend

Answer (score 1):

Just take "nogui" off the command line in your batch file